# How to export data to csv file using JQ

Tags: json, csv, jq, export-to-csv

JSON file example.

```json
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "d130",
      "name": "Abdoulaye, Aminata",
      "division": {
        "id": "d130",
        "name": "",
        "selfUri": "/api/v2/authorization/"
      },
      "chat": {
        "jabberId": "62a0e0b060"
      },
      "email": "Aminata.Abdoulaye@",
      "primaryContactInfo": [
        {
          "address": "Aminata.Abdoulaye@",
          "mediaType": "EMAIL",
          "type": "PRIMARY"
        }
      ],
      "addresses": [
        {
          "address": "Aminata.Abdoulaye@",
          "mediaType": "EMAIL",
          "type": "WORK"
        }
      ],
```

When converting JSON to csv, I have managed to create a csv file containing the data but there is no headers being displayed in the csv file.

```
gc --profile NewProfile users list -a --pageSize 100 | jq-win64 -r -c ".[1,2,3] | [.username,.addresses[].address,.id,.title]| @csv" > test.csv
```

I have managed to create a csv file that contains the headers but no data.

```
gc --profile NewProfile users list -a --pageSize 100 | jq-win64 -r ".? |(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv" > test.csv
```

Then when i try to merge the two together, I get an error saying, string ("Waled.Abdu...) has no keys

```
gc --profile NewProfile users list -a --pageSize 100 | jq-win64 -r ".[1,2,3] | [.username,.addresses[].address,.id,.title] |(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv" > test.csv
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:39688): string ("Waled.Abdu...) has no keys
```

Waled's details in JSON are shown below.

```json
{
      "id": "b143",
      "name": "Abdulkadir, Waled",
      "division": {
        "id": "b143",
        "name": "",
        "selfUri": "/api/v2/authorization/"
      },
      "chat": {
        "jabberId": "63e6e"
      },
      "department": "Canada Solutions",
      "email": "Waled.Abdulkadir@",
      "primaryContactInfo": [
        {
          "address": "Waled.Abdulkadir@",
          "mediaType": "EMAIL",
          "type": "PRIMARY"
        }
      ],
      "addresses": [],
      "state": "active",
      "title": "Engineer",
      "username": "Waled.Abdulkadir@",
      "manager": {
        "id": "f3cc8f83-14c0",
        "selfUri": "/api/v2/users/14c0"
      },
      "version": 4,
      "acdAutoAnswer": false,
      "selfUri": "/api/v2/users/14c0"
    },
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your JSON snippets are incomplete.  Please follow the [mcve] guidelines, even if it means removing irrelevant details from your JSON.

Comment: Please add a complete and valid input snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like:

```
jq -r '["username", "address", "id", "title"],
   (.entities[]
    | (try .addresses[].address // null) as $a
    | [.username, $a, .id, .title] ) 
   | @csv'
```

To circumvent shell quoting issues, consider using the -f command-line option.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I got the (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) that you mentioned. 

I tried to use -f, so jq -r  -f '["username", "address", "id", "title"], but still didnt work for me. 

Error was  "Could not open [username, address, id, title],"

How could i go about implementing the -f command?

Thanks

Comment: Please check the jq manual online.